# Centos PHP-FPM Cron

Tags: centos, cron

I have nginx and php-fpm installed on my Centos vps box. I need to add a cronjob to execute a script every 10 minutes. I tried `crontab -e` with the following in it:

```
*/10 * * * * /path/to/script/script.php
```

However, it's not executing properly. It says there is errors in the php code and there isn't

--

Error when attempting to install php-cli

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-cli.i386 0:5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 for package: php-cli
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php-cli-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 from base has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-cli-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (base)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-27.el5_5.3 is needed by package php-cli-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.i386 (base)
```

Comment: Please include the error messages your receiving.

Comment: It says there's something with the first line. This is the first line: `define("IN_MYBB", 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php-fpm is fastcgi only.. install the php-cli package also

**edit**

You have to enable the repo to install

```
yum -y --enablerepo=webtatic install php-cli
```

Comment: I updated your post with the errors it gives when when trying to install php-cli.

Comment: i don't see an update

Comment: I updated my post instead...I guess it won't let me edit your post.

Comment: how did you install php-fpm?

Comment: I used this: http://moon.mastipoint.net/research/nginx-php-fpm-mysql-on-centos.html

Comment: edited my reply for you

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the errors it's hard to know, but I'd say it's one of:

- The script is executable but missing #!/usr/bin/php at the beginning.
- The script has #!/usr/bin/php but is not executeable.
- The script is not executable and doesn't have #!/usr/bin/php so crond doesn't know how to properly handle it.

If you change your cron to:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/script/script.php
```

Does it work?

Comment: /usr/bin/php doesn't exist...I have php-fpm installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the same configuration.  For whatever reason, after installing php-fpm months ago, I just now noticed PHP wasn't in the path.  The php-cli script couldn't find php, I couldn't find php, phpinfo() didn't help, where was it?  Essentially, installing "php-cli" put php back in the path.  All my websites were running fine but my php-cli script stopped working because php was gone, I just didn't notice till last night.

The solution that worked for me:

Step 1

`yum install php-cli`

> ======================================================================================================================  Package                     Arch                    Version
>   Repository             Size
>   ====================================================================================================================== Installing:  php-cli                     x86_64
>   5.4.13-1.el6.remi                    remi                  2.6 M Updating for dependencies:  php-common                  x86_64
>   5.4.13-1.el6.remi                    remi                  891 k  php-fpm                     x86_64                  5.4.13-1.el6.remi 
>   remi                  1.3 M  php-mysql                   x86_64
>   5.4.13-1.el6.remi                    remi                  134 k  php-pdo                     x86_64                  5.4.13-1.el6.remi 
>   remi                  117 k
>
> Transaction Summary
>   ====================================================================================================================== Install       1 Package(s) Upgrade       4 Package(s)
>
> Total download size: 5.0 M Is this ok [y/N]: y

Hopefully this upgrade doesn't break anything.

Note: I had to add "Remi" repository to get php-fpm.  I really thought php-cli was already installed because this PHP script had been working for months. The script stopped working around the time I switched to php-fpm.

Step 2

Removed #!whatever from first line of script.

`php -l myscript.php`

"No syntax errors detected in myscript.php"

Woot!

Step 3

Updated my crontab with "-f" parameter:

`43 * * * * someuser php -f /home/getposts/myscript.php`

Works!